# Resource returned by PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver can be a "directory". How to avoid it

Tags: java, spring, jar

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new 
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource[] rr = resolver.getResources("/package1/**");
```

If a directory "package1" contains a sub-directory, the code above returns it as a resource. How to find out, if the resource a directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can check like this

```
resource.getFile().isDirectory()
```